# unable to access to localhost remotely with ubuntu 14.04

Tags: server, firefox, ssh, connection, remote-access

I have an old PC that I have set up as a server. I've installed webmin and Plex Media and ssh server. The problem is that I could easily connect to these services in Windows 7 using firefox by just entering localhost:portnumber. Putty works perfectly in Windows 7 by entering the machine's name. But, now I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 as my main OS and I can't access to these services with firefox and Putty. In putty, it just says 'connection refused' and firefox won't load the pages.

Thanks,

Comment: Did you add a key for your ubuntu 14.04 machine.  Keys are recommend for security. https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openssh-server. html.http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/ssh-import-id.1.html is a manpage for a convient way to import ssh keys that you could run from the working windows.